# Tree-view is not working properly in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, treeview

I tried to create a Tree-view. but it's not working properly. collapse icon is not shown. I have mentioned my out and expected output.

Tried code below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script>
<style>

<div id="tree"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tree = [
      {
        text: "Parent 1",
        nodes: [
           {
             text: "Child 1",
        nodes: [
           {
             text: "Grandchild 1"
           },
           {
             text: "Grandchild 2"
           }
       ]
      },
      {
        text: "Child 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 2"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 3"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 4"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 5"
  }
];

$('#tree').treeview({data: tree});
</script>
```

Current output:

[image: Currenct output]

Desired output

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap4 doesn't come with its own icons, you have several options:

1. you can use Bootstrap3 instead
2. you can use another lib with icons, for example, FontAwesome (in this case you need to set "expandIcon" and "collapseIcon" when you initialise the treeview)

```js
 var tree = [
      {
        text: "Parent 1",
        nodes: [
           {
             text: "Child 1",
        nodes: [
           {
             text: "Grandchild 1"
           },
           {
             text: "Grandchild 2"
           }
       ]
      },
      {
        text: "Child 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 2"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 3"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 4"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 5"
  }
];

$('#tree').treeview({data: tree, expandIcon: 'fa fa-plus',collapseIcon: 'fa fa-minus'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="tree"></div>
```

Comment: When I change the bootstrap 4 to 3.3.7 whole document CSS is changing. Is there any way to use both bootstrap 4 and 3.3.7?

Comment: In this case, you can use another lib with icons - please see my updated answer